# Angular Send Feedback

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to use this [angular feedback module](https://github.com/jacobscarter/angular-feedback), however, I'm having a hard time converting the default button that is provided to a bootstrap link button. None of my css changes seem to take effect.

For example

```
/* default
.feedback-btn {
  position: fixed;
  right: 60px;
  bottom: -3px;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
}*/

/*custom button*/
.feedback-btn-link {
  width: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  /*added*/
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

No red border appears and I can't get it to move at all.

I have it as so

```
<li><angular-feedback options="options"></angular-feedback></li>
  </ul>
```

In my footer, HOWEVER, it does not display at all in the the list or even in the footer (right above it).

I just want to use the Bootstrap `btn btn-link` on it and get in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Pass feedbackbutton as option.

**feedbackButton (String)**

Define a custom button instead of the default button that appears on the lower right corner.

```
Default: .feedback-btn
```

For Ex.

```
$scope.options.feedbackButton = 'Your Class Name'
```

Also It will be great if u can share screen shot.